# Unable to add geopackage to PostGIS database using OGR2OGR

Tags: postgis, ogr2ogr, geopackage, osgeo4w

I am using the following command to upload a geopackage into a POSTGIS database using the OSGeo4W shell that comes with QGIS.

```
ogr2ogr -f “PostgreSQL” PG:”host=<hostname>  dbname=<dbname> user=<yourusername> password=<yourpassword>” <dir>\geopackage.gpkg
```

I am following a guide online and know this is the command to use yet I am presented with the following error:

"FAILURE:
Unable to open datasource `DATASOURCE' with the following drivers."

It then lists a bunch of file formats including the gpkg format.

Stumped for ideas on this one!

Comment: what is your actual PG: string (leave out the actual password etc but we need to see the **exact** quoting

Comment: I see characters `“` in your question but in gdal command line the characters must be `"`. If you copy-pasted your command then re-write it from the keyboard for getting the double quotes right.

Comment: @IanTurton my string is: ogr2ogr -f PostgreSQL "PG:host= HOST PG:user=postgres password=PASSWORD dbname=Trafford_test" C:/Users/USER/Documents/Routes.gpkg

Comment: @user30184 I have typed the command manually and that gives the same response

Comment: Does `ogrinfo C:/Users/USER/Documents/Routes.gpkg` work? Does `ogrinfo "PG:host= HOST user=postgres password=PASSWORD dbname=Trafford_test"` work?

Comment: So I have got past that hurdle, I didnt need PG: before user and then put the file path in quotes. Now my DB Name is false even though I know it exists so now my string looks like: `ogr2ogr -f PostgreSQL "PG:host= HOST user=postgres password=PASSWORD dbname=Trafford_test" "C:/Users/USER/Documents/Routes.gpkg"`

Comment: take the space out between `=` and `HOST`

Comment: That solved it, thanks!